# DataTables.js - Dynamically change column priority

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm using datatables with the responsive plugin. When I initialize my datatable, i set a responsive priority on each of my column.

I'd like my users to be able to set their own priority when viewing the table in case one of the column they're interested in is currently hidden because of their screen resolution.

Example:
Datatable as Column A, B, C, D and E

User only see A, B, C and D due to screen resolution.

I'd like the user to be able to switch the responsive priority of D with the responsive priority of E so that E appears instead of D.

Is there any way to achieve this with Datatables?

I cannot find any way to update or set the responsivePriority outside of the datatable initialization.

I've also tried the colReorder plugin and while is allowed me to switch one column with another while they are both visible, when I try to switch a column with an invisible column nothing happens:

```
var table;
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#tabTest').dataTable({
     "columns": [
            {   
          "responsivePriority": 1
        },
        {   
          "responsivePriority": 2
        },
        {   
          "responsivePriority": 3
        },
        {   
          "responsivePriority": 4
        },
        {   
          "responsivePriority": 5
        },
        {   
          "responsivePriority": 5
        }
      ],
      "colReorder": true,
    });
    $(document).on('click', '#switchme', function(){
        $('#tabTest').DataTable().colReorder.move(4,5);
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jcqk5m18/1/

Answer (score 1):

[documentation](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/priority)

```
<tr>
            <th data-priority="1">First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
            <th data-priority="2">Extn.</th>
        </tr>
```

you can use  `data-priority="{some variable}"`